# How to make configurable Retryable maxAttempts and backoff from application.properties file in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, spring-boot, spring-retry

Below parameter, trying to make configurable

```
@Async("threadPoolTaskExecutor")
@Retryable(value = MessagingException.class, maxAttempts = 2, backoff = @Backoff(delay = 5000))
```

I did the following changes in
application.properties file

```
my.app.maxAttempts = 2
my.app.backOffDelay = 5000
```

and

```
@Retryable(value = MessagingException.class, maxAttempts = "${my.app.maxAttempts}", backoff = @Backoff(delay = "${my.app.my.app.backOffDelay}"))
```

But getting following error.
incompatible type. foundjava.lang.String. required 'int'

In build.gradle file I have

```
dependencies {
    compile ("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    compile ("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-mail:2.1.2.RELEASE")
    compile ("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security:2.1.2.RELEASE")
    compile ("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop")
    compile ("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc:2.1.0.RELEASE")
    compile ("org.springframework.retry:spring-retry:1.2.4.RELEASE")
    compile ("io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:2.9.2")
    compile ("io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:2.9.2")
    compile ("io.springfox:springfox-bean-validators:2.9.2")
    compile ("javax.validation:validation-api:2.0.0.Final")
    compile ("org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator")
    compile ("org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator-annotation-processor")
//  compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat', name: 'jackson-dataformat-yaml', version: '2.9.8'
    compile ("com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-xml:2.9.8")
    compile("org.postgresql:postgresql")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
    testImplementation('org.springframework.batch:spring-batch-test')
    testCompile group: 'org.springframework.security', name: 'spring-security-test', version: '4.0.0.RELEASE'
}
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use the expression to

```
@Retryable(value = MessagingException.class, maxAttemptsExpression = "${my.app.maxAttempts}", backoff = @Backoff(delayExpression = "${my.app.my.app.backOffDelay}"))
```

This should work

Comment: Yes i did this recently. Also , you can use that Spring EL to maybe call a method and load from a different place if you want to.

Comment: How to test Retryable is working with configured max attempt?

Comment: @PraveenD use RetryListenerSupport to log the nos of attempt

Comment: @PraveenD put this  in and put logs.
if (++testAttempt < 5) {
        throw new Exception();
      }
      testAttempt = 0;